# How to remedy 'UserWarning: tight_layout not applied: number of columns in subplot specifications must be multiples of one another" in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Come up with the error listed in the title, being

'UserWarning: tight_layout not applied: number of columns in subplot specifications must be multiples of one another"

This is the code that i have so far. Essentially, i am just trying to present it in a neater manner then it is currently. Alternative suggestions to cleaning up the DF are appreciated aswell!

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, (1,2))
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(224)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(234)

BC_grouped.plot(ax=ax1)
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.title("BC_prices")

Gold_grouped.plot(ax=ax2)
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.title("Gold Prices")

IR_grouped.plot(kind="bar", legend=False,ax=ax3)
plt.ylabel("price")
plt.xlabel("date")
plt.title("Interest_Rates")

fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0);
```